# Injective von Neumann algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras, reference-request, oa.operator-algebras

Let $G$ be a non-amenable countable discrete group. How can I show that the group von Neumann algebra $L(G)$ has no injective direct summand?

Comment: I must be missing something. Why can't you take an abelian vN subalg of L(G) and then project onto it?

Comment: There is no reason that this subalgebra will be a direct summand

Comment: @Owen: right, for some reason I had "direct summand as a Banach space" in my mind

Comment: Sorry!...I did not know this function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of the standard proof that $G$ is amenable if $LG$ is injective.  (I believe for instance that it is contained in the book of Brown and Ozawa).

Suppose $p \in LG$ is a non-zero central projection such that $p LG$ is injective.  Thus, there exists a conditional expectation $E: \mathcal B(p \ell^2 G) \to p LG$.  If we view $\ell^\infty G \subset \mathcal B(\ell^2 G)$ as diagonal multiplication operators (for $f \in \ell^\infty G$ and $\xi \in \ell^2 G$ we set $(M_f \xi)(\gamma) = f(\gamma) \xi(\gamma)$), and if we denote by $\tau$ a tracial state on $pLG$ then we can construct a state $\varphi$ on $\ell^\infty G$ by the formula $\varphi(f) = \tau \circ E(p M_f p)$.  If $\gamma \in G$ then we have
$$
\varphi( f \circ \gamma) = \tau \circ E(p M_{f \circ \gamma} p)
$$
$$
= \tau \circ E(p \lambda_{\gamma^{-1}} M_f \lambda_{\gamma} p) = \tau( (p\lambda_{\gamma^{-1}}p) E(p M_f p) (p \lambda_{\gamma}p) ) = \varphi(f). 
$$
Thus $\varphi$ is an invariant mean for $G$ and so $G$ is amenable.